# Temperature readings are high on income eletrical feeds to the breaker box

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I am buying a home built in 2006 the incoming temp the temp on the left side is 200 degrees and the right side is 80 with full load on. My inspector sees a tie wrap stuck down the hookup on the left side and says that may be the cause of the heat difference and should be removed.

Comment: That's more than what a tie wrap would do.  What make/model is the panel?

Comment: My inspector says it is a square d  if that helps

Comment: Materials: 150 Amp - Interior main disconnect / distribution panel (square D).

Answer (score 1):

With aluminum service conductors if an anti oxide compound was not used the connection may be failing. Also if the terminals were not properly torqued this can happen. The 2017 NEC has a new section on torque requirements for this very reason. Re torquing the service requires hot gloves and flash gear if the service is live. I have never found a zip tie to cause an over heating problem. But have found many terminations that needed to be tightened both with copper and aluminum wire (I have found more problems with aluminum than copper).

Comment: Does just squirting joint paste on the end of the service inlet conductor and then tightening down do any good? Or does one have to disconnect, clean oxide off with emery cloth or a wire brush through antioxidant joint paste, add more joint paste, and then torque to specs? Would one have to go so far as to spread the individual strands to deliver paste to the joint

Comment: It is best to clean the outside contact area, if there is a spare inch of wire I would cut it off and clean the terminal then wipe anti oxide compound on the outer surfaces it doesn't take much. This level of cleaning the power needs to be off, I have done hot work like this but many will not (have only done this on life critical systems that we could not shut down).  I also pull the terminal set screw and add some compound on the threads when the terminal / set screw is aluminum. Re Torque the screw may work if the corrosion is not bad. The tempature will drop within minutes if  it works.

Comment: I can imagine "exploratory" tightening of the lugs on the service entrance conductors in the panel without making a temperature measurement.  Would this be unwise?

Comment: Just call the power company and have them shut it off at the meter.  A lot of smart meters these days have contactors which can be remotely thrown by the power company.

Comment: In some heavy industrial facility's many panels are checked once a year with thermal imaging 2 of the facilities I have worked at checked at 6 months without a thermal image (torque driver used) on all aluminum feeders it did amaze me on very large motors how often there were problems. We do also find problems with copper but just a fraction compared to aluminum.